# Force JAX-RS to serialize my class to a JSON object

Tags: java, json, serialization, jax-rs

I have class which is a decorator around an inner list. I would like to use this class as a DTO in my JAX-RS service. Its code as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "movies")
public class MoviesResponse implements List<Movie> {

    @XmlElement(name = "movie")
    protected List<Movie> movies;

    /* tons of delegate methods */

}
```

I need to support both application/xml, and application/json.
The format is fixed, it has to be like

```
<movies>
 <movie>
  <foo />
 </movie>
 <movie>
  <foo /> 
 </movie>
</movies>
```

... in XML, and

```
{
 "movie": [
 {},{}
 ]
}
```

...in JSON. 
XML works perfectly fine, but JSON looks like this:

```
[{},{}]
```

As you may suspect, if I don't implement the List interface, it generates the the format I need. So I guess the serializer is being smart and treating it as List thus serializing it into an array. But I need to serialize it into an object. How can I do this, implementing the List interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Jackson is your serializer, you could configure the `ObjectMapper` to [`WRAP_ROOT_VALUE`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRAP_ROOT_VALUE). You would do that in the [`ContextResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html). So that the same configuration is not used for all types, you can use two different configured `ObjectMapper`s, one for the list class, and one for the rest. For example

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    final ObjectMapper listMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final ObjectMapper defaultMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        listMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        listMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

        listMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
        defaultMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        if (type == MovieList.class) {
            return listMapper;
        }
        return defaultMapper;
    }  
}
```

The [`MessageBodyWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) used for marshalling will call the `getContext` method, passing in the class it's trying to marshal. Based on the the result, that is the `ObjectMapper` that will be used. What `WRAP_ROOT_VALUE` does, is wrap the root value in a object, with the name being the value in `@JsonRootName` or `@XmlRootElement` (given JAXB annotation support is enabled- see [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-Features))

Test:

```
@Path("/movies")
public class MovieResource {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response getMovieList() {
        MovieList list = new MovieList();
        list.add(new Movie("I Origins"));
        list.add(new Movie("Imitation Game"));
        return Response.ok(list).build();
    }
}
```

> `C:\>curl -v -H "Accept:application/json" http://localhost:8080/api/movies`
>   **Result:**
>   `{
>     "movies" : [ {
>       "name" : "I Origins"
>     }, {
>       "name" : "Imitation Game"
>     } ]
>   }`

#### UPDATE

So I noticed you have the list as being `protected`. Maybe you might later want to extend the `MovieList` class. In which case, this

```
if (type == MovieList.class) {
    return listMapper;
}
```

would bot be viable. You would instead need to check is the type [`isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

```
if (MovieList.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
    return listMapper;
}
```