# Provide backwards compatibility to Moxy deserialization with Jackson

Tags: rest, jackson, jersey, moxy, jackson2

Since Jersey projects start with Moxy JSON serializer by default, I used it for a multi module REST project. But writing clients to this REST API had it quirks, [due to this known problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322605/how-to-return-a-json-object-from-a-hashmap-with-moxy-and-jersey), that moxy doesn't work really well with Maps.

I've migrated the development branch of my code to Jackson, where hashmap serialization works well without the entry[] array, making it easier to write new non-jersey clients to the project. But I would also need to keep backwards compatibility somehow if possible, for already written clients. How could I achive this with Jackson?

Sadly some hashmaps dont have predetermined keys, so the solution showed in the link cant be implemented, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Do you have tests to show that Jackson serialization _wouldn't_ be backward compatible? The Jackson provider supports most JAXB annotations. For most use cases, the serialization should still be the same.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to give the server the payload with the "entry array" like hashmap, and Jackson thrown a JsonMappingException not surprisingly. I solved other quirks, but I cant find a good solution for this one.

Comment: You might be able to use a custom JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer

Comment: I just found another thing moxy did automatically, but it's a pain in the ass with Jackson :(