# Serialize Java List of Lists to XML and JSON using Jackson

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, restlet

In my Restlet based APIs, using the Restlet Jackson extension, I am attempting to serialize a Java object to both XML and JSON, and am unable to get the formats that I expect (that the existing API already publishes) with a nested list or multidimensional array.

Here is my POJO that generates the correct JSON:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement( localName = "table")
@JsonInclude( JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class TableResponse {

  protected List data;
  protected String[] columns;

  public TableResponse( String[] columns, List<List<String>> data ) {
    this.columns = columns;
    this.data = data;
  }

  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "data")
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "row")
//@CanIAddSomeAnnotationHereForNestedListElements?
  public List<List<String>> getData() {
    return data;
  }

  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "columns")
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "column")
  public String[] getColumns() {
    return columns;
  }
}
```

JSON of TableResponse, I would like to see JSON like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Row 1 Cell A",
      "Row 1 Cell B"
    ],
    [
      "Row 2 Cell A",
      "Row 2 Cell B"
    ],
    [
      "Row 3 Cell A",
      "Row 3 Cell B"
    ]
  ],
  "columns": [
    "Column 1",
    "Column 2"
  ]
}
```

And I would expect to be able to make XML like this:

```
<table>
    <data>
        <row>
          <value>Row 1 Cell A</value>
          <value>Row 1 Cell B</value>
        </row>
        <row>
          <value>Row 2 Cell A</value>
          <value>Row 2 Cell B</value>
        </row>
        <row>
          <value>Row 3 Cell A</value>
          <value>Row 3 Cell B</value>
        </row>
    </data>
    <columns>
        <column>Column 1</column>
        <column>Column 2</column>
    </columns>
</table>
```

But instead I get this XML (XML of TableResponse), which loses a dimension:

```
<table>
    <data>
        <row>Row 1 Cell A</row>
        <row>Row 1 Cell B</row>
        <row>Row 2 Cell A</row>
        <row>Row 2 Cell B</row>
        <row>Row 3 Cell A</row>
        <row>Row 3 Cell B</row>
    </data>
    <columns>
        <column>Column 1</column>
        <column>Column 2</column>
    </columns>
</table>
```

Using an alternate POJO structure, I can acheive the XML I expect for a nested list (it is a pain to initialize the data and instantiate the classes for this structure) but then the JSON is not what I want:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement( localName = "table")
@JsonInclude( JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class TableResponseForXML {

  protected List data;
  protected String[] columns;

  public TableResponseForXML( String[] columns, List<Row> data ) {
    this.columns = columns;
    this.data = data;
  }


  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "data")
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "row")
  public List<Row> getData() {
    return data;
  }

  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "columns")
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "column")
  public String[] getColumns() {
    return columns;
  }


  public static class Row {
    private List<Value> values;

    public Row( List<Value> values ) {
      this.values = values;
    }

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "row", useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "value")
    public List<Value> getValues() {
      return values;
    }
  }


  public static class Value {
    private String value;

    public Value( String value ) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

JSON of TableResponseForXML (Objects are wrapping the inner lists):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "values": [
        "Row 1 Cell A",
        "Row 1 Cell B"
      ]
    },
    {
      "values": [
        "Row 2 Cell A",
        "Row 2 Cell B"
      ]
    },
    {
      "values": [
        "Row 3 Cell A",
        "Row 3 Cell B"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "columns": [
    "Column 1",
    "Column 2"
  ]
}
```

Some of the dependencies in my project are:

- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.5.3
- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:2.3.5
- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.jackson:2.3.5
- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.json:2.3.5

Is there a way to make nested lists work the way I expected between JSON and XML with the first POJO structure? The multi-dimensional JSON Array is simpler to work with than an object wrapping each list, and is the existing published spec for this API.

A side note, I also tried the suggestion in [Jackson: different XML and JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391554/jackson-different-xml-and-json-format), but failed to get my XmlAdapter/@XmlJavaTypeAdapter to be used here with restlet.

Comment: I'm used to dealing with GSON for creation of JSON strings, so I can only speak on that.  From my experience, I've had to experiment a great deal with various data types to get what I wanted and found that HashMaps<String,Object> or LinkedHashMaps<String,Object> along with a combination of ArrayList<sometype> worked best.  You may need to experiment with these to see the outcome from jackson.

Answer (score 2):

It seems difficult to handle these both formats only using Jackson annotations. For your use case, I think that you need to implement a custom serializer that handles separately JSON and XML.

This serializer looks like the following:

```
public class TableResponseSerializer extends StdSerializer<TableResponse> {
    private MediaType mediaType;

    public TableResponseSerializer(MediaType mediaType) {
        super(TableResponse.class);
        this.mediaType = mediaType;
    }

    private void serializeJson(TableResponse swe, 
            JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        (...) 
    }

    private void serializeXml(TableResponse swe, 
            JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
       (...)        
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(TableResponse swe, 
                          JsonGenerator jgen,
                          SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        if (mediaType.equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)) {
            serializeJson(swe, jgen, sp);
        } else if (mediaType.equals(MediaType.TEXT_XML)) {
            serializeXml(swe, jgen, sp);
        }
    }
}
```

The serializeJson method will build the JSON content:

```
private void serializeJson(TableResponse swe, 
        JsonGenerator jgen,
        SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
    jgen.writeStartObject();      

    // Data
    jgen.writeArrayFieldStart("data");
    for (List<String> row : swe.getData()) {
        jgen.writeStartArray();
        for (String rowElt : row) {
            jgen.writeString(rowElt);
        }
        jgen.writeEndArray();
    }
    jgen.writeEndArray();

    // Columns
    jgen.writeArrayFieldStart("columns");
    for (String column : swe.getColumns()) {
        jgen.writeString(column);
    }
    jgen.writeEndArray();

    jgen.writeEndObject();
}
```

and the serializeXml one, the XML one:

```
private void serializeXml(TableResponse swe, 
        JsonGenerator jgen,
        SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {

    jgen.writeStartObject();      

    // Data
    jgen.writeObjectFieldStart("data");
    jgen.writeArrayFieldStart("row");
    for (List<String> row : swe.getData()) {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeArrayFieldStart("value");
        for (String rowElt : row) {
            jgen.writeString(rowElt);
        }
        jgen.writeEndArray();
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
    jgen.writeEndArray();
    jgen.writeEndObject();

    // Columns
    jgen.writeObjectFieldStart("columns");
    jgen.writeArrayFieldStart("column");
    for (String column : swe.getColumns()) {
        jgen.writeString(column);
    }
    jgen.writeEndArray();
    jgen.writeEndObject();

    jgen.writeEndObject();
}
```

The last step consists in configuring the serializer on the `ObjectMapper` instance that is used by the Restlet Jackson converter. For this you need to extend both `JacksonConverter` and `JacksonRepresentation` classes.

First the `JacksonRepresentation` class where you override the `getObjectMapper` method to register your serialiser for the `TableResponse` class:

```
public class CustomJacksonRepresentation<T> extends JacksonRepresentation<T> {
    public CustomJacksonRepresentation(MediaType mediaType, T object) {
        super(mediaType, object);
    }

    public CustomJacksonRepresentation(Representation representation,
                         Class<T> objectClass) {
        super(representation, objectClass);
    }

    public CustomJacksonRepresentation(T object) {
        super(object);
    }

    @Override
    protected ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = super.createObjectMapper();

        if (getObjectClass().equals(TableResponse.class)) {
            SimpleModule mod = new SimpleModule("");    
            mod.addSerializer(new TableResponseSerializer(getMediaType())); 
            objectMapper.registerModule(mod);
        }

        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Then the `CustomJacksonConverter` class that will use this kind of representation when necessary:

```
public class CustomJacksonConverter extends JacksonConverter {
    protected <T> JacksonRepresentation<T> create(MediaType mediaType, T source) {
        return new CustomJacksonRepresentation<T>(mediaType, source);
    }

    protected <T> JacksonRepresentation<T> create(Representation source,
             Class<T> objectClass) {
        return new CustomJacksonRepresentation<T>(source, objectClass);
    }
}
```

To register the `CustomJacksonConverter` class, you can rely on the `getRegisteredConverters` of the `Engine` before starting your component. Don't forget to remove the default `JacksonConverter`.

```
List<ConverterHelper> converters = Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredConverters();
JacksonConverter jacksonConverter = new JacksonConverter();
for (ConverterHelper converter : converters) {
    if (converter instanceof JacksonConverter) {
        jacksonConverter = (JacksonConverter) converter;
        break;
    }
}

if (jacksonConverter!=null) {
    converters.remove(jacksonConverter);
    converters.add(new CustomJacksonConverter());
}
```

This way you will have the output content you want for both XML and JSON based on the content negotiation (`Accept` header).

Comment: Hi Thierry, can I ask how to force Restlet to use XStream instead of Jackson?