# Register JodaModule in Jax-RS Application

Tags: jackson, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jackson-modules

I'm writing a Jax-RS application using Jersey, and Jackson2 under the hood to facilitate JSON i/o. The service itself works fine, but I'd like to improve it by having the Jackson mapper automagically serialize/deserialize date and date-times to JodaTime objects.

I'm following the documentation [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda) and have added the relevant jars, but I'm lost on this instruction:

```
Registering module

To use Joda datatypes with Jackson, you will first need to register the module first (same as with all Jackson datatype modules):

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
```

I've tried to do this in the custom class that extends jax.ws.rs.core.Application, but I'm not at all confident in that solution. I'm currently getting this error:

```
Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class org.joda.time.DateTime] from String value ('2014-10-22'); no single-String constructor/factory method
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@3471b6d5; line: 7, column: 25]
```

Other than the general impression that this module registration needs to happen at application (servlet?) startup, I have no idea what to do with this information. Do I need to annotate a custom class with something in particular to have it picked up ? Should I be extending some class ?

The examples I find on StackOverflow usually stick it in `main()` and call the mapper directly, but I'm relying on Jackson Databinding so the examples aren't relevant. Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll basically want to create/configure/return the `ObjectMapper` in a  [`ContextResolver`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29202555/2587435). Something like

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }  
}
```

If you are using package scanning to discover your resources, then the `@Provider` annotation should allow this class to be discovered and registered also.

Basically what happens, is the the [`MessageBodyReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) and [`MessageBodyWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) provided by Jackson, used for unmarshalling and marshalling, respectively, will call the `getContext` method in the `ContextResolver`, to determine the `ObjectMapper` to use. The reader/writer will pass in the class (in a reader it will be the type expected in a method param, in a writer it will be the type returned as-a/in-a response), meaning we are allowed to use differently configured `ObjectMapper` for different classes, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29202555/2587435). In the above solution, it is used for all classes.

Comment: How can I achieve this with a JAX-RS client?

Comment: @thomas.mc.work it should work just the same for the client. You can explicitly register it, if for some reason it doesn't get picked up automatically