# Android: how to properly consume Joda LocalTime object property from WebService

Tags: android, jax-rs, retrofit, jodatime

I currently have this POJO on my REST server.

```
public class IntervalHolder {

    private final LocalTime start;
    private final LocalTime end;

}
```

This `IntervalHolder` class is also returned as a property in a larger object:

```
public class Foo {
    private final List<IntervalHolder> intervals;
}
```

I've already debugged my server output, and my `LocalTime` values are correct, but when I consume them on my Android App, the values come out wrong. The automatic parsing seems to be incorrect.

I'm using Retrofit in my app:

```
@GET("foo")
Call<List<Foo>> foo();
```

My REST endpoint:

```
@Path("/foo")
public class Foo{
    @Path("/")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public List<Foo> listAll() {
        //return ArrayList<Foo>
    }
}
```

I've read several answer in which I'm supposed to build a converter, but they only approach cases where the actual type returned **IS** in fact a `LocalTime` (or `DateTime`, etc). But that is not my case.
I want to be able to properly parse a property **inside** my object. Every single other property in my object seems to be fine.

I'm probably missing something very obvious here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's incorrect about it? If you are using Jackson on he server for serialization, you can [add the joda module](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29523169/2587435). Maybe that will solve your problem, whatever is it is.