# Jersey 1.x with Jackson : Customising the response JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

I am using Jersey 1.19 to implement a rest api and Jackson to provide JSON support. My resource entities are deeply nested and I want to flatten them out before sending them over. I also want to provide support for filtering based on query params. Example `GET /users/1234` returns the whole user resource while `GET /users/1234?filter=username,email` will return the user resource with only the given fields included.

The approach I have currently taken is a subclass of `JsonSerializer` which flattens the hierarchy, but cannot handle parameter based filtering as it is independent of the request/response cycle. Google search pointed me to `MessageBodyWriter`. Looks like what I need but the [writeTo method](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.19/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html#writeTo(T,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.reflect.Type,%20java.lang.annotation.Annotation[],%20javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType,%20javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap,%20java.io.OutputStream)) which handles the serializing doesn't take any parameter that would let me access the request, and hence the query params. So I am confused how to access those params in this method.

Any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I am confused how to access those params in this method.

You can inject [`UriInfo`](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) with `@Context` into the `MessageBodyWriter`. Then call `uriInfo.getQueryParameter()` to get the params. For example

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class YourWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Something> {

    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;

    ...
    @Override
    public void writeTo(Something t, Class<?> type, Type type1, Annotation[] antns, 
            MediaType mt, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> mm, OutputStream out) 
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        String filter = uriInfo.getQueryParameters().getFirst("filter");
    } 
}
```

Another option is to use a `ContextResolver` and use preconfigured `ObjectMapper`s for different scenarios. You can also inject the `UriInfo` into the `ContextResolver`. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29202555/2587435)

Comment: Thanks. Injecting UriInfo was what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass a list in and/or you can expose the Request object if you want to go that route.

Try ...

```
@Context
UriInfo uriInfo;
@Context
HttpServletRequest request;
```

or try altering your Rest method to something like...

```
@GET
@Path("/myMethodLocator")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
...
public <whatever type you are returning> myMethod(List<String> filterByList) ...
...
```